# MvvmCross on iOS - Strategies for Saving and Restoring State

Tags: ios, save, mvvmcross, state, restore

The Construct, Init, ReloadState, Start construction pattern for creating view models in MvvmCross is not implemented for iOS. It is only implemented for Android and Windows Phone.

Has anyone who is writing an iOS app using MvvmCross got any strategies, patterns or examples for saving and restoring state?

Comment: I'm wondering: where did you read that this isn't implemented for iOS?

Comment: Hi,

If you look at the issues on the MvvmCross GitHub site, Stuart Lodge has explained the issue that iOS behaves differently to Android and Windows Phone


https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1016

Comment: Can you elaborate more about (a) specific situation(s) where you need more control than what is currently available?

Comment: I am not using storyboards for various unrelated reasons, So i have none of the out of the box functionality provided.